# How to install a Windows Feature on Docker container (Windows 2016 Server) that requires a "server restart"?

Tags: powershell, docker, container, windows-server-2016

I try to install the Windows feature "`NetworkController`" on a docker container on Windows 2016 Server TP4, using Powershell.
After I run "`Add-WindowsFeature NetworkController`", I get the message:

"You must restart this server to finish the installation process."

[image]

When I now check again (without having done anything else yet) with Get-WindowsFeature, it has the install state "InstallPending".

[image]

Now I am not sure what "restart this server" means 100%, but I suppose it means I am supposed to restart the host machine, since there is nothing else to restart (and the container itself is just a container, not a VM as with a Hyper-V approach).

So I try the following aproaches:

**Approach (1)**

I stop the docker container using `docker stop iisdemo`, then restart the host machine (my Windows 2016 server) and then restart the docker container, using `docker start iisdemo`.

But when I check for the NetworkController, it's still not installed.

[image]

**Approach (2)**

In a second attempt, I add the feature, then restart the docker container **without** restarting the Windows 2016 server, just running

`dock restart iisdemo`.

Now something strange happens, when I try to check for the features via `Get-WindowsFeature *network*`, the process of collecting data stops at 57% and the container exists by itself.

[image]

When I attach to the docker image again:

```
> docker start iisdemo
> docker attach iisdemo
> powershell
> Get-WindowsFeature *network*
```

I am back to where I started:

[image]

**Approach (3)**

Another third approach obviously should not work, but I tried it anyway and restarted the Windows 2016 server/host without stopping the docker container at all. Needless to say, this did not work either (same behaviour as approach 1, the container exits at 57% of collecting data).

**Approach (4)**

Running a "`shutdown -r -f -t 10`" inside the container does not help either. After the restart, the `NetworkController` is still not installed.

---

Note: I tried to use both Docker containers as well as Windows containers (created and managed via Powershell commands), makes no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neil Peterson vom Microsoft replied to me on Twitter about this, seems to be a bug: https://twitter.com/nepeters/status/705451007233257472?cn=cmVwbHk%3D&refsrc=email

[image]